# Keep absolute div visible on small screen

Tags: html, css

This is hard to describe, but I'll try my best.

I am making a template for a forum. In each thread the posts are aligned under each other. The posts are centered. I want a div containing the username, title and posts floating to the left of the thread. An image describes best: http://nclabs.org/screenshots/stackoverflow.png. The red arrow points to the div I'm talking about, and the red line shows the position of the div without `position: absolute`.

The problem is, because the div is absolute positioned, when the screen gets too small the div "falls off" the page, instead of showing a scrollbar. I realize this is normal behaviour of `position: absolute`.

**How would I make the div float to the left of the (centered) post without it falling off the page when the screen is too small?**

And here is some CSS:

```
#wrapper { // the whole page is wrapped in this div
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
}

#thread .threadauthor { // the divs containing the username, etc
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: -7.5em;
    margin-top: .5em;
    left: 0;
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="threadauthor">
<div class="Webmaster">nightcracker</div>
<div class="Webmaster"><small>Webmaster</small></div>
<div class="postcount"><small>Posts: 24</small></div>
</div>

<div class="threadpost">
```

Comment: is there any parent element that has css `overflow:hidden` property applied?

Comment: Yes, but removing the `overflow: hidden` property doesn't fix anything. It's not related either. I'm talking about the overflow of the whole page, which is perfectly set to auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving all your HTML and related styles, so it's difficult to answer directly. Is the `.threadpost` a fixed width? If so, then since `.threadauthor` is a fixed width as well (that 7.5em of negative margin) you can put them into the same container `div` like this:

```
<div class="post">
  <div class="author"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

You can then style `.author` and `.body` into a fixed-width two-column layout, here's a couple of options for doing that (there are a lot more if you search for them):

1. Give `position: relative` to `.post`, `position: absolute` to `.author` and `margin-left` equal to `.author`'s width to `.body`.
2. Float either `.author` or `.body` to the side.

This should give you better results.